# Using redux-form, how can I reset the form values from another component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Here is a demo of my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-form-reset-problems

I am using redux-form 7.2.0 and am trying to reset the form values from another component that is not wrapped by the ReduxForm HOC.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reset } from 'redux-form';

class MoodAnnouncement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.resetMood = this.resetMood.bind(this, event);
  }

  resetMood(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(this.props.reset('SearchFiltersForm'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mui-panel">
        <button
          className="mui-btn mui-btn--primary mui-btn--raised"
          disabled={this.props.MoodCheckerForm.values === undefined}
          onClick={this.resetMood}
        >Reset Mood
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    MoodCheckerForm: state.form.MoodCheckerForm,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { reset })(MoodAnnouncement);
```

When I click the reset mood button that is in another component away from the form, I'm receiving the error **this.props.dispatch is not a function**, so I assume there is a different way to dispatch the reset action from within the connect HOC.

How can I reset the form values from another component that is using the react-redux connect HOC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the [Remote Submit example](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/remotesubmit/).

There are a couple issues.

Your form names do not match. The only reason `MoodChecker.resetMood()` works is because the `reduxForm()` HoC binds the form name to `reset()` when passing in the prop. So the incorrect name passed is actually being ignored.

`MoodControls.resetMood()` only has to call the bound action creator `reset()` from the props, making sure to pass in the right form name. When using the `connect(mapStateToProps: func, mapDispatchToProps: object)` form, the object passed as the second argument is automatically bound to `dispatch` via  `bindActionCreators()`.

```
class MoodControls extends Component {
  // ...

  resetMood(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.reset('MoodCheckerForm');
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  MoodCheckerForm: state.form.MoodCheckerForm
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { reset })(MoodControls)
```

Comment: Damn! Such a dumb oversight! Thanks for your answer!